# Calling constructor after object Definition

Tags: c++, object-composition

```
class first{
    int fa,fb;

    public:
        first();
        first(int x,int y);
        void display();
};

first::first():fa(0),fb(0){
       }

first::first(int x,int y):fa(x),fb(y){
}

void first::display(){
    cout<<fa<<" "<<fb;
}

class second{
    first f;
    int sa,sb;

    public:
        second();
        second(int x,int y,int a,int b);
        void display();
};

second::second():sa(0),sb(0){
}

second::second(int x,int y,int a,int b):f(x,y),sa(a),sb(b){
}

void second::display(){
    cout<<"The Numbers are ";
    f.display();
    cout<<" "<<sa<<" "<<sb<<endl;
}
```

I apologize if this question has been asked already.

This a simple code to demonstrate the working of nested classes in c++.
However, in the class `second`, the object `f` even though it has been defined before, I am able to call a constructor on it using the construtor of `second` class.
How is it possible to call a constructor on an already defined instance of a class?

Comment: Nested classes or inner classes are something else.  Here you just have composition.

Comment: There are no nested classes here.

Answer (score 0):

The object `first f;` is a member of `second`.  That means every `second` contains a `first`.  So in the process of creating a `second`, a `first` must be created.  Your mem-initializer `f(x,y)` specifies exactly how to create `f` while creating the `second` object.

Answer (score 0):

You mix different concepts, when a variable defined in a function:

```
void foo()
{
    Foobar f; // f is defined and default initialized  here
    Foobar d { 123 }; // d is defined and initialized with 123
}
```

and declared as a field within a `class` or `struct`:

```
struct boo {
    Foobar f; // f is declared as member of type boo and how it will be
              // initialized will be known in boo's constructor
              // not here

    boo() {} // f is default constructed
    boo( int i ) : f { i } {} // f is initialized with i
};
```

to make things worse for you in c++11 you can pass parameters to field constructor in place:

```
struct boo {
    Foobar d { 123 };  // d would be initialized with 123 if otherwise is not set in boo's constructor

    boo( int i ) : d { i } {} // 123 is ignored and d is initialized with i
    boo() {} // d { 123 } is used
};
```

so still even if you pass parameters to field  how field is initialized is defined in boo's constructor.